# View is re-initialized after DragGesture onChanged

Tags: swiftui, draggesture

The following code shows an orange screen with a green circle in the lower right. The circle can be dragged.

```
import SwiftUI

struct DraggableCircle: View {
    @Binding var offset: CGSize
    @State private var previousOffset: CGSize

    var body: some View {
        Circle().fill(Color.green)
            .frame(width: 100)
            .offset(self.offset)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local)
                    .onChanged { event in
                        print("\nDragGesture onChanged")
                        self.offset = CGSize(width: event.location.x - (event.startLocation.x - self.previousOffset.width),
                                             height: event.location.y - (event.startLocation.y - self.previousOffset.height))
                    }
            )
    }

    init(offset: Binding<CGSize>) {
        print("Init with offset \(offset.wrappedValue)")
        self._offset = offset
        self._previousOffset = State(initialValue: offset.wrappedValue)
        print("offset = \(self.offset), previousOffset=\(self.previousOffset)")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var circleOffset = CGSize()

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            Rectangle().fill(Color.orange)
                .overlay(
                    DraggableCircle(offset: self.$circleOffset)
                )
                .onAppear {
                    self.circleOffset = CGSize(width: reader.size.width / 2,
                                               height: reader.size.height / 2)
                    print("size: \(reader)\n")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

If you run and tap the green circle (to begin a drag gesture), the following appears in the console:

```
Init with offset (0.0, 0.0)
offset = (0.0, 0.0), previousOffset=(0.0, 0.0)
size: GeometryProxy(base: SwiftUI._PositionAwareLayoutContext(base: SwiftUI.LayoutTraitsContext(context: AttributeGraph.AttributeContext<SwiftUI.VoidAttribute>(graph: __C.AGGraphRef(p: 0x00007f84b6a05ff0), attribute: AttributeGraph.Attribute<()>(identifier: __C.AGAttribute(id: 42))), environmentIndex: 4), dimensionsIndex: 1, transformIndex: 3, positionIndex: 2), seed: 1, viewGraph: Optional(SwiftUI.ViewGraph))

Init with offset (187.5, 323.5)
offset = (187.5, 323.5), previousOffset=(187.5, 323.5)

DragGesture onChanged
Init with offset (0.0, 0.0)
offset = (0.0, 0.0), previousOffset=(0.0, 0.0)
```

What I expected to happen, is that when you drag the circle, it can be smoothly dragged somewhere else on the screen.

What actually happens, is when dragging starts, `DraggableCircle.init` is called again, which resets the offset and places the circle right in the middle. Why is this?

Note: when you move the `@State previousOffset` into the `ContentView`, the issue disappears. But I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code based on your comment. In my code this drag gesture workes fine. The only bug right now I see is in the first time drag gesture is activated. Maybe this will lead you to your desired solution.

```
        struct DraggableCircle: View {
    @Binding var circleOffset: CGSize
    @State private var previousOffset: CGSize

    var body: some View {
        Circle().fill(Color.green)
            .frame(width: 100)
            .offset(self.circleOffset)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { event in
                        print("\nDragGesture onChanged")
                            self.circleOffset = CGSize(width: event.location.x - (event.startLocation.x - self.previousOffset.width),
                                                       height: event.location.y - (event.startLocation.y - self.previousOffset.height))
                }
                .onEnded { event in
                    self.circleOffset = CGSize(width: event.location.x - (event.startLocation.x - self.previousOffset.width),
                                               height: event.location.y - (event.startLocation.y - self.previousOffset.height))

                    self.previousOffset = self.circleOffset
                }
        )
    }

    init(offset: Binding<CGSize>) {
        print("Init with offset \(offset.wrappedValue)")
        self._circleOffset = offset
        self._previousOffset = State(initialValue: offset.wrappedValue)
        print("offset = \(self.offset), previousOffset=\(self.previousOffset)")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var circleOffset = CGSize()

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            Rectangle().fill(Color.orange)
                .overlay(
                    DraggableCircle(offset: self.$circleOffset)
                )
                .onAppear {
                    self.circleOffset = CGSize(width: reader.size.width / 2,
                                               height: reader.size.height / 2)
                    print("size: \(reader)\n")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to remove the State variable from the ContentView. The reason is, that in my original code (not the compressed example I posted), other views depend on it.

Comment: @BartvanKuik I have changed the code, but that isn't perfect solution for now.

Comment: I don't see any difference between your current code and my code? I think something went wrong copy/pasting :)

Comment: @BartvanKuik Ahh no copy pasting was perfectly fine.. i have added a `onEnded` modifier to Drag Gesture. It solves the problem of drag places the circle right in the middle. It just happens for the first time.